# SaaS - How to prove users/client that they are using the same code always in the server?

Tags: security, encryption, hash

Let's suppose we have an open source project running in a server.

Is there a common way to prove users that we're using the same code as the one published?

Comment: For what kind of service and with what kind of contract?  You concerned with version mismatches between client/server?

Comment: I was thinking for a security service, where it's necessary that server side code doesn't change. No I'm not concerned for version mismatch, I'm concern by adding the server code a malicious script...

Comment: You have a basic trust issue here. Obviously the application can't provide the hashes for its own files, because it could spoof them. So you'd have to have some sort of layer that is not the application to check if the code changed. But then your users would have to trust that... Maybe you should look at zero knowledge proofs, might be something there you could use.

Comment: Good point. About those Zero knowledge proof, Can you expand that idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never an implicit guarantee that the remote service is what's described in its manifest, though generally the reputation of the service is what's directly considered.

What's more, SaaS itself is just a delivery model, and doesn't necessarily define a set of protocols or contracts between a client and a service.  It merely defines an approach to building and serving a public platform.  It's a term more relevant for describing the building process of a service and it's intended market than it is for describing the nitty-gritty operational details.

If such a thing needed to be implemented as part of the contract between the client and server, one could look at implementing a native hashing solution using HMACs.  An identity mechanism could be implemented using salted access tokens similar to OAuth, but using the files of the codebase to generate the checksum.  This would guarantee that if the code executed properly once, it would be the same code running so long as the hash generated did not change (though there's once again no guarantee that the hash being publicly exposed was properly generated)

Such a thing would sound redundant however, on top of the SSL security most services generally tend to use.

The long and short of it is that if you have concerns about the service being offered over a public API, then there is probably a pretty good reason its reputation precedes it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking in creating a security API from a scratch, but there seems to be no industry standard to prove that same code as published is being used ...

Comment: I think generally this is because the services are so closely tied to business ventures that need to manage their reputation, and therefore are expected to maintain the integrity of the code internally or risk losing clients.

Comment: I think you're right, but I would think that eventually there is going to be a company that certifies these kind of things...